# Website thumbnail image, title and description like facebook does where you paste in a link for android

Tags: java, android

I am developing something like facebook does when we paste a link which loads image, title and description from that URL. Any java library is available for doing this ?. I am not looking for website screenshot image. You can get the screenshot image of a website by using the following libs :

```
bluga webthumb: http://webthumb.bluga.net/home 
Girafa: http://www.girafa.com/
PageGlimpse: http://www.pageglimpse.com/
scURLr: http://www.scurlr.com/com.boxysystems.scurlr.Main/Main.html
Websnapr: http://www.websnapr.com/premium%5Fservices/
```

Can anyone done this before? I would also like to know how i can load image and details from an email id.

Answer (score 0):

use tempoary webview load that url, you will get fav icon, title search little bit you may get more info.